# ClusterManager from android:android-maps-utils changed and is not retrocompatible

Tags: google-maps, android-maps-utils

Last Friday my project was running smoothly, Today Monday seems as Google updated 
android-maps-utils and now the project is full of error ;-(

The big problems is in the next line:

```
mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(mClusterManager);
```

because seems as now ClusterManager isn't an OnCameraChangeListener anymore. The problem raise because in my dependencies I was having

```
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+'
```

So, it was updating automatically. My problem now is I have not idea about what version I was using before the update, there is not straight information about the versions history on Github or at least I wasn't able to find it. Does anybody know how to find out which version was the previous one (or I will have to try from 4.0)?

EDIT: Solved, I was taking a look to the Maven Repo:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.maps.android/android-maps-utils

EDIT 2:

compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3.4' did the trick and the project return to work as before ;-)

Comment: Thanks for that. My code was compiling yesterday and started playing up this morning.  :)

Answer (score 2):

Great, I can confirm it works.

Changing from:

```
dependencies {compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+'}
```

to

```
dependencies {compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3.4'}
```

in my build.gradle